# Convert from JSON data to current time DIFFERENCE

Tags: javascript, json, datetime

I have some JSON data created time expressed as posted:"2015-09-28T17:15:23.633" . I need to express it in my chrome extension popup window as current time different as in "Posted: 2 seconds ago" .

When I am firing an event each time in my extension i get a time expressed as mention above. 
i want the users to see the event firing time difference with users current time. as in " few seconds ago... / 3 minutes ago " like that.
I can do that in c# but is there any way to do it in java script ?
Any working example or links would be so helpful.
Thanks in advance.

this is what i have tried from the example suggestion but it doesnt show any thing

```
 //My JSON Data
 "postcreated":{
    "name":"test",
    "created":"2015-09-28T17:15:23.633",
 }

 //in my js to show the time difference

 var jsonData = JSON.parse(myData);                   
 timeSincePostInSeconds = (Date.now() -Date.parse(jsonData.postcreated.created)) / 1000 ;

 var timeSincePostInSeconds = document.getElementById('createdAt');
```

Comment: Noda Time is a .NET library.  It doesn't have anything to do with JavaScript.

Comment: Also, you need to show what you've tried and what did or didn't work.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MattJohnson thanks for the feedback. i have tried to explain my issue by editing  the question.

Comment: Why have you re-added the `nodatime` tag? Again, if this is in Javascript it is *not* a question about Noda Time.

Comment: @JonSkeet i have removed the tag.  except that any solution how to calculate the difference in my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at *Date.parse()*. This will convert the given string into a Date object. I guess what you are looking for is something like:

```
var timeSincePostInSeconds = (Date.now() - Date.parse("2015-09-27T17:15:23.633")) / 1000
```

What happens here: `Date.parse(dateString)` creates a date object same as `Date.now()` does. Using the `-` operator on objects will call the valueOf method of this object. The Date object will return the unix timestamp (milliseconds since 1.1.1970). So if you substract  *dateString* from *now* you get the difference in milliseconds - divide this one by 1000 to get the difference in seconds.

Comment: `Date.now()` returns the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. That *doesn't* depend on the time zone at all. `Date.parse()` does, but that's different.

Comment: i have tried  but it doesn't show anything. i have added the code i have tried with your suggestion.

Comment: @user12: What *exactly* do you mean by "it doesn't show anything"? That code just sets a variable... I wouldn't expect it to display anything anywhere... that part's up to you.

Comment: when i have tried to put this variable inside my code to view the result                                     var timeSincePostInSeconds = document.getElementById('createdAt');         the output is nothing

Comment: @user12: Well if the code you've updated in the question is anything to go by, you're doing the calculation and then completely ignoring it by calling `getElementById('createdAt')`. Why not just look at the value of `timeSincePostInSeconds` after executing the code in this answer?

Comment: @user12: I guess what you want to do is something like: 
`var timeSincePostInSeconds = (Date.now() - Date.parse("2015-09-27T17:15:23.633")) / 1000;
document.getElmentById('createdAt').innerHTML = timeSincePostInSeconds;`

Comment: @JonSkeet you're thanks for the hint! I deleted the hint about the timezones.